# Book on mechanisms

Tags: mobile-robot, mechanism

I wanted to know if there is any sort of archive of mechanisms that contains a brief description of mechanisms like there type of motion and forces involved. Not lengthy derivations and other stuff.

Comment: Would something like '507 Mechanical Movements' be of use to you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion based.

Comment: Thread is still open for more suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Adnan, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it is a good idea to include details of what what you would like to achieve, what you have tried, what you expected to see and what you actually saw. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. If you edit your question to make it more clear, flag it for moderator attention and we can reopen it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanisms and Mechanical Devices Sourcebook - Nicholas P. Chironis & Neil Sclater, McGraw-Hill, ISBN 0-07-011356-4. The format of this book is more akin to a scrapbook of newspaper clippings, but it is a good visual "food-for-thought" collection spanning several generations of mechanism design for a broad range of applications and industries.